# Creating a single trigger for Insert/Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Assuming I have Table A which is a transaction table. And Table B which is a history table.

Whenever a row is inserted or updated in Table A, a new row should be inserted in Table B.

The Status column of Table B should change to INSERTED or UPDATED respectively.

How to handle this from a single trigger?

Comment: What are the differences between Table A and B? A = B + Status ?

Comment: Yes. B has all the columns of Table A plus an additional column Status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is quite simple:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TableA_IU ON dbo.TableA FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT dbo.TableB (Column1, Column2, Status)
SELECT
   I.Column1,
   I.Column2,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted) THEN 'UPDATED' ELSE 'INSERTED' END
FROM Inserted I;
```

If you also wanted to handle deletions, that can be done in a single statement, too:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TableA_IUD ON dbo.TableA FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT dbo.TableB (Column1, Column2, Status)
SELECT
   I.Column1,
   I.Column2,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted) THEN 'UPDATED' ELSE 'INSERTED' END
FROM
   Inserted I
UNION ALL
SELECT
   D.Column1,
   D.Column2,
   'DELETED'
FROM Deleted D
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM Inserted
);
```

Wow, there are a lot of outright-wrong and semi-wrong (at least in being overcomplicated) answers given so far.

Comment: thanks for your comment.can you make your trigger for insert,update,delete

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both tables:

- has an "Id" column as primary key.
- has the same schema, except that history table has an extra "Status" column at the end.

You can create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableA_InsUpd
ON dbo.TableA
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    Insert Into TableB 
    Select i.*, 'INSERTED'
    From inserted i
    Where not exists ( Select * From deleted d Where d.Id = i.Id )

    Update B
    Set [Status] = 'UPDATED',
    Field1 = i.Field1,
    Field2 = i.Field2
    From TableB B
    Inner Join inserted i On i.Id = B.Id
    Where exists ( Select * From deleted d Where d.Id = i.Id )

    Update B
    Set [Status] = 'DELETED'
    From TableB B
    Inner Join deleted d On d.Id = B.Id
    Where not exists ( Select * From inserted i Where i.Id = d.Id ) 
END
```

[Here is a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3922/2) with the complete code

(Note this will fail if a record Id is deleted and then inserted again)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this answer fails to meet the requirements (such as insert on update, not update on update).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER YouTriggerName 
   ON  TableA 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    DECLARE @type NVarChar(15)=
        CASE when not exists(SELECT * FROM inserted)
            THEN 'Deleted'
        WHEN exists(SELECT * FROM deleted)
            THEN 'Updated'
        ELSE
            'Inserted'
        END

    /*
    TableB should contains all the columns of TableA
    OR tweak it to suit your need 
    */
    IF @type = 'Deleted' BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TableB
        SELECT *, @type Stat FROM deleted
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TableB
        SELECT *, @type Stat FROM inserted  
    END

END
```

**NOTE**
You will get this error if TableB has identity on since we use (select *)

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'TableB' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Answer (score 0):

this is tested.here employee and employee have same table structure.0 means updated and 1=inserted,2=deleted

```
     Alter trigger trgTest on dbo.employee
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE,Delete
as
Begin
Set noCount on
if exists(select e.id from deleted e inner join inserted i on e.ID=i.id )
Begin
insert into Employee1
select id,name,0 from inserted
End
else if exists(select e.id from Employee1 e inner join deleted d on e.ID=d.id)
Begin
insert into Employee1
select id,name,2 from deleted
End
else
Begin
insert into Employee1
select id,name,1 from inserted
End

End
```

Comment: The joins in the EXISTS clauses are completely unnecessary. The second EXISTS query is also unnecessary. Using two separate INSERT statements is unnecessary.